Why do L2s not support blob transactions?
Is there a specific reason L2s don't allow blob transactions?
Example
Arbitrum

This means that an L3 Orbit chain on top of an Arbitrum L2 will use calldata when posting L3 transaction data to the underlying L2. The L2 Arbitrum chain will then be able to post data to a L1 data availability layer like Ethereum using blobs.


Is this because it's already "cheap" ? Or is there a logic issue that I'm not catching
